# How can I let a class add onto my paint function?

Tags: java, jcomponent

I know that is poorly worded, but I don't know how to word it better. Essentially I have my own JComponent `MyComponent` and it paints some stuff onto its graphics. I want it to paint its stuff, then call a method to finish the paint, here is an example:

```
public class MyComponent extends JComponent{
    // etc
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.drawSomething(); // etc

        // Once it is done, check if that function is exists, and call it.
        if(secondaryPaint != null){
            secondaryPaint(g2);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in a different class:

```
// etc
MyComponent mc = new MyComponent()
mc.setSecondaryDrawFunction(paint);

// etc

private void paint(Graphics2D g2){
    g2.drawSomething();
}
```

I'm not sure how lambdas work or if they are applicable in this situation, but maybe that?

Comment: Do you mean abstract classes? You could make an abstract class which inherits from JComponent and override the paintComponent method in which you paint and as last call you can call your abstract method defined by your abstract class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No lambdas, but the Function interface will work

You can do :

```
public class MyComponent extends JComponent{
    // etc
    Function<Graphics2D, Void> secondaryPaint;
    public MyComponent(Function<Graphics2D, Void> myfc){
        secondaryPaint = myfc;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        //g2.drawSomething(); // etc

        // Once it is done, check if that function is exists, and call it.
        if(secondaryPaint != null){
            secondaryPaint.apply(g2);
        }
    }

    static class Something {
        public static Void compute(Graphics2D g){
            return null;
        }

        public Void computeNotStatic(Graphics2D g){
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Something smth = new Something();
        new MyComponent(Something::compute); // with static
        new MyComponent(smth::computeNotStatic); // with non-static
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to give it a function that is not static?

Comment: Yes of course, I'll edit in 2 minutes to show you how